# How to change Android ViewPager page title text size depending on the screen size

Tags: android, android-viewpager, text-size

Having 3 pages in the `ViewPager` and running on a tablet vs running on a smartphone the text size for the page title must change.

any ide?

I try to set `PagerTabStrip` text size in the xml but that was not possible

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to set PagerTabStrip text size in the xml but that was not
>   possible

Did you? Because you can definitely do that. If you take a look at the [`PagerTitleStrip` source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/7dbbadd44f1d8b14990cf413bace64e1535a2564/core-ui/java/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.java#L69) you'll see it uses the following attributes to style the title text.

```
private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[] {
    android.R.attr.textAppearance,
    android.R.attr.textSize,
    android.R.attr.textColor,
    android.R.attr.gravity
};
```

And you can set any one of those in your XML, so in your case something like:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pagerTitleTextSize" />
```

Where `pagerTitleTextSize` is just a text size in whatever `values` folder you need. For instance:

`values`

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="pagerTitleTextSize">22sp</dimen>

</resources>
```

[image: phone]

`values-sw600dp`

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="pagerTitleTextSize">64sp</dimen>

</resources>
```

[image: tablet]

There's also [`PagerTitleStrip.setTextSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html#setTextSize(int,%20float)) if you wanted to handle it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks that was strange your right dunno what happened